# Linker error with array of structs in header

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors

I am working on a small piece of a large project.  The project was initially written in C, and sort-of-transitioned to C++ around 6 years ago (I first heard of the project about 3 weeks ago...)

Everything compiles just fine.  The error I'm having is from the linker:

```
libBlah.so.0.0: undefined reference to `Extent::structArray'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The error occurs with whichever executable it tries to link first; there are a handful of executables, each of them depending on the `Extent` class and the `structArray` data member.  Before trying (and failing) to link the other executables, it successfully links the entire `libBlah` library.

In `Extent.hpp`, in the `public` section of the `Extent` class declaration, `structArray` is declared (and hackily initialized) thus:

```
struct structThing
{
    const char *name;
    int compress_flag;
    bool (*func1)( byte*, int32, ByteArray&, int );
    bool (*func2)( byte*, byte*, int32, int32& );
};

// This isn't actually a magic number
static const int num_things = 7;

static structThing structArray[ num_things ];

struct structArray_init
{
    structArray_init()
    {
        structThing init[] =
        {
            { "none", 0, NULL, NULL },
            { "thingA", 1, funca1, funca2 },
            { "thingB", 2, funcb1, funcb2 },
            { "thingC", 4, funcc1, funcc2 },
            { "thingD", 8, funcd1, funcd2 },
            { "thingE", 16, funce1, funce2 },
            { "thingF", 32, funcf1, funcf2 }
        };

        for( int i = 0 ; i < num_things ; ++i )
        {
            structArray[i] = init[i];
        }
    }
};

static structArray_init thingy_init;
```

All 12 of the functions (funca1 through funcf2) are static functions of `Extent`, declared later on in the public section of the header.

The build is managed by CMake.  Basically, in the CMake each of the separate dependent programs is given the entire `libBlah` library as a dependency.  I've tried playing around with the linking order, to no avail.

Prior to this linker error, I was having compilation errors resulting from initializing `structArray` within a non-static function of `Extent`, which was obviously problematic.

Comment: [OT] That comment above the magic number saying it's not a magic number was really funny!

Comment: I think it would be better to actually put the class declaration around the above code (since the code itself doesn't show that it's all inside a class.) Nothing much, just the `class` and `public` lines and the braces would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem *might* be that you are forgetting to actually define the `static` members in your CPP file, like so: (in `Extent.cpp`)

```
Extent::structThing Extent::structArray [Extent::num_things];
Extent::structArray_init Extent::thingy_init;
```

Comment: You are exactly correct.  We ended up switching to just initialize the members in `Extent.cpp` and that much, at least, works.